# How to solve this with a circular buffer?

Tags: c, circular-buffer

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing the insertion of one element before others in an array without having to rearrange all elements with a for loop. I have tried a circular buffer implementation, but it doesn't work and I am getting frustrated. I made the question simpler, so it will hopefully be easier for everyone.

```
int * buffer = (int *) calloc(L_buffer, sizeof(int));
int i, j, K, out;

while(1) {

    i = rand();
    K = 3;

    /* Calculate output */

    out = buffer[i]  buffer[i+1]  + buffer[K];

    /* Shift array elements by one and insert new value */

    for(j = 0; j < L_buffer-1; j++) 
        buffer[j+1] = buffer[j];

    buffer[0] = new_value;
}
```

Solution:
I edited the solution of @Eric Postpischil to suit my needs. By extending the function to the following, I can advance the current index in both directions and always wrap around.

```
int * cb_element(CircularBuffer *cb, ptrdiff_t i) {

    if ( cb->current < 0)
        cb->current += cb->size;

    ptrdiff_t index = cb->current + i;

    if ((size_t) index >= cb->size)
        index -= cb->size;


    return &cb->array[index];
}
```

So I can

```
out = *cb_element(&cb, i) + *cb_element(&cb, i+1);

cb.current--;
*cb_element(&cb, 0) = new_value;
```

Really neat!

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work" and "kind of works"?

Comment: This is for an audio effect. The first version just distorts the signal completely. The last version generates a proper effect, but there are some glitches like popping noises. Maybe the last version actually is right. If so, the bug lies somewhere else.

Comment: This doesn't look like correct to me: `if (--p_dynamic < p_start)`

Comment: Why not simply ... `p[counter++ % length]`? (`counter` for `i` or `K` or ...)

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Why not? I first decrement and if the moving pointer is lower than the first address I go to the last address in the buffer

Comment: @neolith How do you make sure that the `p_dynamic` will be within the bounds of the array? For example, if `p_dynamic == &array[0]` then it will contain an invalid address after `--p_dynamic`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Look at what I wrote after /* and after every iteration */

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, carefully reread your question: It asks about "accomplishing this" without ever defining what "this" really is. Please [edit] your question to clarify that. As it stands, it's impossible to answer without guessing.

Comment: The post was very detailed and confusing before. I already edited it earlier to make it easier to understand for others. I did it once more. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `int *p_dynamic =  array[0];
> int *p_start = array[0];
> int *p_end = array[L_array - 1];`

You have not told us what these variables are intended to do, so we do not know if you are using them in a sensible way for their intended purposes.

> `if (--p_dynamic < p_start)`

When `p_dynamic` points to `array[0]`, the behavior of `--p_dynamic` is not defined by the C standard. The standard defines pointer arithmetic only from elements 0 of an array to just beyond the last element of the array.

> `int K = 3;
> int i = some_int;
> int output;
>
> output = array[i] + array[i+1] + array[K];`

Again, you have not told us the intent, so we do not know what you are trying to achieve here. Why is `K` 3? Is that a fixed constant in every use of your code or just an example? Does it have any relationship to `i`? Do you mean `array[K]` to mean the actual element `array[3]` will always be added, or do you mean that the element at offset 3 from the current start of the circular buffer will be added?

> `if (p_dynamic[K] > p_end &&
> p_dynamic[i] < p_end &&
> p_dynamic[i+1] < p_end)`

This makes no sense because `p_dynamic` is a pointer to an `int`, so `p_dynamic[K]` is an `int`, but `p_end` is a pointer to an `int`, so `p_dynamic[K] > p_end` attempts to compare an `int` to a pointer. I suspect you are attempting to ask whether the element `p_dynamic[K]` would be beyond the end of the array. You might do that with `p_dynamic + K > p_end` except, as with `--p_dynamic`, if it is beyond the end of the array, the pointer arithmetic is not defined by the C standard.

Simplify your code by making a function to help you access array elements. Make a structure that describes the circular buffer. To start simply, I will assume you have a fixed buffer size of `Size` eleemnts.

```
typedef struct
{
    int array[Size];
    ptrdiff_t current;
} CircularBuffer;
```

The member `current` will be the index (subscript) of the element that is currently oldest in the buffer, the current “start” of the circular buffer. (The `ptrdiff_t` type is defined in the header `<stddef.h>`. It may be used for array subscripts.

Then make a function that gives you a pointer to the element with index `i`:

```
int *CBElement(CircularBuffer *cb, ptrdiff_t i)
{
    ptrdiff_t index = i + current;
    if (Size <= index) index -= Size;
    return &cb->array[index];
}
```

Then you can refer to array element `K`, for example, as `*CBElement(&cb, K)`:

```
output = *CBElement(&cb, i) + *CBElement(&cb, i+1) + *CBElement(&cb, K);
```

You can also put new values in the array:

```
*CBElement(&cb, i) = NewValue;
```

To advance the buffer, update the `current` member in the obvious way and put a new value in the new last element (`*CBElement(&cb, Size-1)`).

This should simplify the task of getting the code working. After it is working, you can consider optimizations and refinements of the buffer implementation.

Comment: I edited the code accordingly. This is not an array but allocated memory. Thus I can move the pointer freely. I will try to see if I can write a function. I think this problem is too complex without the full code. But when you post the full code, people complain that you should describe it.

Comment: Re “Thus I can move the pointer freely”: The C standard does not define pointer arithmetic or comparisons outside the bounds of an array regardless of whether the array is allocated statically, automatically, or dynamically.

Comment: I made the question easier, Thank you for the effort so far, but I just got more confused

Comment: Our prof told us to implement a circular buffer this way and it worked. I didn't know it was undefined behavior.

Comment: I am trying your solution, but since I have a dynamically allocated memory section I don't know how to implement the structure.

Comment: I tried to implement it your way. It seems like the cleanest solution, but I really don't see how to advance the current ptrdiff here. I have to go backwards and it can't take on negative values. It does advance in the positive direction but only once and then it stays at 1.

Comment: @neolith: To use the structure with a dynamically allocated array, change the `array` member to `int *array;` and initialize it to point to the dynamically allocated memory. `current` never needs to be negative. It is always the index of the “start” of the circular buffer, so it has a value from 0 up to the index of the last element in the allocated array.

Comment: But current has to be changed somehow. I put cb.current—; and then put the element with *CBelement(&cb, 0) = new_value; I also don’t need to advance the current index, I need to decrement it to emulate the behavior of pushing all elements by one and pushing a value before them.

Comment: I think the problem is that this is not a classical circular buffer. I need to insert in the backward direction and read in the forward direction.

Answer (score 0):

> There is probably a more elegant way than doing it with so many lines.

"mod" the array index access with `% L_array` using unsigned math.  Further, if `L_array` is an unsigned power-of-2, `% L_array` results in simply emitted *and* code.

```
output = p_dynamic[i] + p_dynamic[(i+1)% L_array] + p_dynamic[(i+2)% L_array];
```

---

Note: `--p_dynamic < p_start` is never true unless code relies on *undefined behavior*.  The valid values to compare `p_dynamic` against are `array[0]...array[length]`, That does not include `array[-1]`.

Insertion looks suspicious for a circular buffer.  There should be no reason for a `for` loop to *shift*.  Instead adjust references to the ends of the buffer.

Consider using below:

```
array = calloc(L_array, sizeof *array);
size_t length = 0; // current length
size_t begin = 0;  // Index of eldest sample
size_t end = 0;    // Index to store the next sample
```

To insert

```
if (length < L_array) {
  length++;
  array[end] = new_value;
  end = (end+1)%L_array;
}
```

To extract

```
if (length > 0) {
  length--;
  sample = array[begin];
  begin = (begin+1)%L_array;
}
```

To sample 3 elements starting at `i`

```
if (length >= 3) {
  output = array[(begin+i) % L_array] + array[(begin+i+1) % L_array] +
      array[(begin+i+2) % L_array];
}
```

Comment: I just tried the solution with the modulo a few seconds before and it also has glitches. I also can't compare the pointer to an array index, because I allocated memory with calloc. Therefore I stored the first and last entry right after allocation and am using the pointer to the allocated memory is p_dynamic.

Comment: I cannot work with arrays here, because all of this happens in an interrupt routine. A circular buffer is the only way to make this in time. The processor has 225 MHz.

Comment: @neolith The suggested coding approach does not  use _arrays_, but a pointer and  3 integers effecting a circular buffer.  I have successfully coded many times solitons like this in interrupts service routines.  Given data is adjusted in interrupts, any non-ISR access and manipulation of the buffer warrant protection from interrupts for a short time.  The CPU speed is not an issue.

Comment: I made the question easier, because I am getting confused myself. Hope it helps. Sorry if your effort so far has been for nothing.